# Java - How to get object value in JSON array?

Tags: java, json

i have a JSON like example below and i'm trying to get some values, for example value of.

```
results.shipper.id



{
    "results": [
        {
            "updated": false,
            "notification": false,
            "some_data": {
                "id": 15989,
                "pieces": 0,

            },
            "shipper": {
                "updated": false,
                "notification": false,
                "id": 1587,
                "parent": {
                    "updated": false
                },
```

I'm trying to get value by this way:

```
    String test = shipmentData.getJSONObject("shipper").getString("id");
```

But it always throws a exception. I think, that exception is caused because of the i am not accessing to the values via "results" array.

How can i easy access to the value what i need.

I tried find some helpers (Gson, fast-json, etc..) but it seems to be a quite complicated for using (i would like to work with JSON tree for direct access to values "on-the-fly" or access to values like to a object, it means.. Object.InnerObject.value ).

So question is how can i do it right?

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: "Peel the onion" one layer at a time.  First convert the JSON to Lists/Maps.  The outermost entity will be a Map ("JSONObject").  It contains an entry with a key of "results" whose value is a List ("JSONArray").  So get the JSONArray named "results" from the original JSOSNObject.   The entries in the List are Maps ("JSONObject" again), so iterate through the List and get each Map.  Each Map contains a key/value named "shipper", where the value is another Map.  That Map contains a key/value pair named "id", whose value is an Integer (not a String).  Do this one step at a time, logging between.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

JSON needs to be traversed in order to access `id`:

```
JSONArray results = shipmentData.getJSONArray("results");
JSONObject first = results.getJSONObject(0);
JSONObject shipper = first.getJSONObject("shipper");
Integer id = shipper.getInt("id");
```

Parse int to string:

```
String id = String.valueOf(shipper.getInt("id"));
```