# How to search in a JSON file

Tags: java, json

I am having a JSON file that consists of JSON Objects and arrays. The file looks like this:

```
{"Report": {"Information": [
{
  "table_name1": [
     {"ID": 312},
     {"LASTNAME": "TESTER2"},
     {"GUID": "ADSA31321"},
     {"PHONE_MOBILE": 931024}}
],
  "table_name2": [
     {"ID": 312},
     {"PID": "TESTER2"},
     {"GUID": "ADSA31321"}
   ]
}
]}}
```

I am trying to update the values within the table_name array. The problem is that this name is dynamic and not a static name given to the array.

I am using the Java class below to reach ID.

```
if( inputJs.getJSONObject("Report").get("Information") instanceof JSONArray) {
    JSONArray val= inputJs.getJSONObject("Report").getJSONArray("Information");
    for(int i = 0; i < val.length(); i++) {
        JSONArray jsa2=val.getJSONArray(i); 
        for(int j = 0; j < jsa2.length(); j++) {
            JSONObject jso= jsa2.getJSONObject(j);  
            if(jso.equals("GUID")) {
                jso.put("GUID", GetRegExpr(3));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This line : `JSONArray jsa2=val.getJSONArray(i);` creates the error below:

```
org.json.JSONException: JSONArray[0] is not a JSONArray.
```

even though "table_name1" is a JSONArray.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Json path ease the job of extracting that data -> https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath/blob/master/README.md

Comment: Is your issue resolved.. ?

Comment: Hi. I Just tested using the answer from RakChun Jang and Mayur Agarwal and it worked.!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please replace your code with the one below

```
 if( inputJs.getJSONObject("Report").get("Information") instanceof JSONArray){

        JSONArray infoArray = inputJs.getJSONObject("Report").get("Information");

    for (int i = 0; i < infoArray.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject information = infoArray.getJSONObject(i);

        Iterator<String> keys = information.keys();

        while (keys.hasNext()) {
            String tableName = keys.next();
            JSONArray table = information.getJSONArray(tableName);

            for (int j = 0; j < table.length(); j++) {
                JSONObject data = table.getJSONObject(j);
                String k = data.keys().next();

                if (k.equals("GUID")) {
                    data.put("GUID", GetRegExpr(3));
                }
            }
        }
    }
    }
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your quick response. When I am trying your suggested code it creates an error in this line : JSONObject jso= jsa2.getJSONObject(j); 
Error : The method getJSONObject(String) in the type JSONObject is not applicable for the arguments (int)

Comment: Hi. I've checked it. Should I modify this sample code after JSONObject jsa2= val.getJSONObject(i); ? I mean use something like: 
Iterator<?> keys = jsa2.keys();
.... ?

Comment: Thank you very much for all the help!

Comment: I would like to ask one more silly question. GUID will contain a value. How can I get this value? Thanks again and sorry for those silly questions but I am really new to JSON.

Comment: this link will help you better: 
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22386344/java-how-to-get-object-value-in-json-array

Comment: Great! Thank you very much for all the help once again!

Answer (score 2):

Try this...

```
informationList = new JSONObject().getJSONObject("Report").getJSONArray("Information");

        for (int i = 0; i < informationList.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject information = informationList.getJSONObject(i);

            Iterator<String> keys = information.keys();

            while (keys.hasNext()) {
                String tableName = keys.next();
                JSONArray table = information.getJSONArray(tableName);

                for (int j = 0; j < table.length(); j++) {
                    JSONObject data = table.getJSONObject(j);
                    String k = data.keys().next();

                    if (k.equals("GUID")) {
                        data.put("GUID", "edit ...");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

If I were you, I would use other library like Gson...

Answer (score 1):

you can try like this :

```
if( inputJs.getJSONObject("Report").get("Information") instanceof JSONArray){

    JSONArray val= inputJs.getJSONObject("Report").getJSONArray("Information");
    for(int i=0;i<val.length();i++){
        JSONObject jsa2=val.getJSONObject("table_name"+i);   // table_name1,table_name2,...

        for(int j=0;j<jsa2.length();j++){   
            JSONObject jso= jsa2.getJSONObject(j);

            if(jso.equals("GUID")){
                jso.put("GUID",GetRegExpr(3));

            }
     }
}
```

Comment: Hi. I used this name as an example. The real name will be something like "Information", "Exams" etc..